# Constant error in when opening Visual Studio 2012 Help Viewer 2

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Months ago, I installed offline full Visual Studio 2012 Help packages and it worked well. But now whenever I try to access the contents in Help Viewer 2 I got a constant error indicating

> The value of the property 'setUserPreferenceLang' is null or undefined, not a Function object.

[image]

I don't remember if I did anything ambiguous or wrong. I also googled the matter but just found this error unsolved in Microsoft feedback front-end.

Comment: Try installing update 4

Comment: Did it happen to you too @Gilad?

Comment: Not exactly but similar

Comment: Control Panel + Internet Options, Advanced tab, untick "Display a notification about every script error".

Comment: @HansPassant that option has been unticked, already.